# tag helper to integrate a non-valued attribute

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Attempting to generate:

```
<div data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown content">
```

with the tag helper.  However there appears to be no syntax for non-valued attributes

```
<%= tag(:div, :class => "f-dropdown content", data: {dropdown-content: ""},  :'aria-hidden' => true, :'tabindex' => "-1") %>
```

and different variants all lead to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= tag(:div, data: {dropdown_content: ""}, class: "f-dropdown content") %>
```

Your code is failing because `dropdown-content` is not valid key here.
Tag helper converts `dropdown_content` to `dropdown-content` in data.